# Are there radioactive elements that can be seen to diminish/change with the naked eye?

Tags: radioactivity, half-life, isotopes

That is, after creating a quantity of a radioactive isotope with a half-life of several seconds or minutes, could the sample be seen to change into decay products with the naked eye? (Excluding nuclear bombs!)

I understand it may not be possible to create a large sample of radioactive material with a short half-life in the first place, nor to safely observe it's decay.

In any case, I think it would be fascinating to watch as a lump of solid material transmutes or vanishes before your eyes in a matter of seconds.

Comment: You seem to assume that a radioactive substance disappears when it decays.  That is not the case:  It turns into some other substance, and depending on chemistry and I don't know what all else, the other substance will not necessarily look any different from the original.  (E.g., cobalt-60 changes to nickel when it decays.)

Comment: @jameslarge Understood - so can a large lump of cobalt-60 (or another radioactive material) be seen to visibly shrink or become lighter as it decays?

Comment: Don't think that you would want to be close enough to observe with your "naked eye" any macroscopic sample which is so intensely radioactive that it would transform into decay products in a time period of seconds to minutes.

Comment: @SamuelWeir Good point - let's say observing through heavy glass is allowed. :-)

Comment: @Nat I'd say yes - I'm not talking about a phase change from solid -> liquid or solid -> gas, but rather radioactive decay.

Comment: @RobertF My point is, it won't be _seen_ to become lighter or smaller because it _doesn't_ (for any practical purpose) become smaller or lighter.  The atomic mass of pure $^{60}$Co is approximately 59.934, and the atomic mass of pure $^{60}$Ni is approximately 59.931.  It loses about 0.005% of its mass.  You could measure that with a sensitive laboratory balance, but you aren't going to _see_ it.

Comment: @jameslarge Ok - so cobalt-60 may not be good example, but are there other elements that could be seen to "magically" change before your eyes as they decay?

Comment: Your best bet would be a chemical substance _containing_ some radioactive nuclide, which undergoes a spontaneous chemical reaction, changing into some visibly different substance as the nuclide changes.  I don't know of any good examples--I'm neither a nuclear scientist, nor a chemist.

Comment: Also, don't loose track of what @SamuelWeir said:  The radioactivity of different substances tends to be inversely proportional to their half-lives.  Substances with half-lives in the tens of years are dangerous. You want a _visible amount_ of something with a half-life measured in minutes? I can't even comprehend...  Also, where are you going to get it? Pull it fresh from the core of an operating nuclear reactor?

Comment: I can't seem to find it, but an identical question was asked within the last month or so.

Comment: @BenCrowell Ah ok - I looked but didn't find a similar question.

Answer (score 1):

There's no practical way to do it, but if you had a quantity of Hg$_{195}$, it would decay over the course of a day or so (half-life = 10 hours) into isotopes of gold and platinum.  Not the "seconds to minutes" that you asked about, but somewhat visible.

Most other transitions would be less dramatic to the eye.  Solid -> gas is almost invisible unless the gas is very dense.  Gas -> solid might create a bit of dust on the vessel, but it's hard to get a lot of mass in as a gas.

The real problem is that anything with a half-life short enough to have a visible decay would have to be created/isolated immediately before the viewing.  Since we can only create such substances at tiny rates, the decay overwhelms the production and you never have any sizeable quantity.